# IE11 flexbox: opacity affecting layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I've been employing a flexbox layout for a navigation bar, and I've noticed a strange behaviour in Internet Explorer 11. Doesn't happen in Chrome, FF or Edge. I've made a fiddle to demonstrate:

https://jsfiddle.net/6L06251k/

The following is a further stripped-down version of the fiddle's code:

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Menu item</button>
      <ul id="submenu"><li><button>Submenu item</button></li></ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
}

#submenu {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

li:hover #submenu {
  opacity: 1; /* RULE A */
}

button:focus + #submenu {
  opacity: 1; /* RULE B */
}
```

The problem is that when I hover over the outer menu `<ul>`, triggering RULE A and changing the submenu's `opacity` from 0.5 to 1, the height of the outer menu increases by a few pixels. This doesn't happen if the hover rule sets the opacity to, say, 0.999. I don't see why the opacity of an element should be affecting its layout, nor why this should only happen when the opacity becomes 1, but not 0.999!

Also, if I instead change the submenu's opacity using RULE B, by tabbing to focus on the outer `<button>`, then the height change in the outer menu doesn't occur, even though the exact same style is being applied.

For the fiddle, I could resolve this by just using an `opacity` of 0.999, but this solution doesn't work for the actual project in which I've encountered this issue. It's not easy to tell why, so I'm hoping that by understanding the underlying mechanism of this quirk, I can figure something else out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `display: inline-block` there may appear such a strange spacing behaviour. To fix this issue you can simply do the following

1. Analyze which div has the `display: inline-block` attribute, in your case it's `#submenu`.
2. Add `font-size: 0` to the parent div of the div which has the `display: inline-block`, in your case the `li`. With `font-size: 0` you remove completely the spacing caused by the font.
3. Next and final step is to add the font-size again to those divs
   which should display some text by adding `font-size: initial`, in your case the `button`.

The updated CSS code would now look something like this

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
ul {
  background: #aaf;
  list-style: none
}
li {
  font-size: 0;
}
button {
  background: #afa;
  font-size: initial;
}
#submenu {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
}
li:hover #submenu {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button>Menu item</button>
      <ul id="submenu">
        <li>
          <button>Submenu item</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thanks - that's worked in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9roq5yj7/), and in my main project. Do you have any information or resources about why this was happening? I'm guessing this isn't something that wouldn't happen in modern browsers? It's just a very strange behaviour for opacity, to me, and the way that it was influenced by _which_ selector was triggering the CSS change was particularly odd.

Comment: @JosephO'Donnell Great, no problem. Glad could have helped. The problem with inline-block is that the whitespace between your divs becomes visible on screen. Because this is the way inline-block behaves it actually doesn't matter how modern your browser is. It's actually interesting that the other browsers displayed it correctly. Sometimes you won't even notice the whitespace but in your case you noticed it because of the change of the navigation height on hover. Later on if you don't want to deal with those whitespace issues you could simply do everything with flex.

Comment: David Walsh wrote an [article](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) about this topic and even pointed more ways out of how you could solve the whitespace issue but I think in your case the font-size method is the best.

Comment: I've encountered the situation discussed in that article before, and I'm not sure that this is exactly what's happening here! The behaviour doesn't occur if the element is at 0.999 opacity, which wouldn't normally happen for inline-block whitespace. Also, the problem is still present even if I remove all whitespace from the HTML in [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ca02y941/)

Comment: @JosephO'Donnell Ah yeah, you're totally right my bad. It's indeed not because of the whitespace. The problem is that the two buttons have a different height on page loading in the Internet Explorer. You can see this if you set the opacity of the div #submenu to 1. If you look closely you can see by the #submenu button that there is, compared to the first button, a border at the bottom which is overlapping the ul. But if you now set the opacity of this to less than one you can't see the border at the bottom anymore. And now when you hover the opacity goes to one and the border appears again.

Comment: And with the display:flex at the top Flexbox tries to resize your navigation height to fit the content again. So my guess is that it's Flexbox which cause this unwanted effect. To solve this you can either remove the display: flex from the form or simply disable grow on the ul by adding flex: 0 0 auto.

Comment: You are a genius.